# Jquery ajax request increases exponentially on each request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use Jquery-ajax calls to get information from a api and store it. The problem I encounter is the following:

When first call is made call everything seems normal. When the call is made 2nd time (after 1 min )again one only call takes place but with 3rd call 2 times sendData function is getting called ,4th time 4 times sendData function is called.

Please tell me where i am going wrong.Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://blockchain.info/ticker",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      crossDomain: true,
      processData: true,
      async: false,
      success: function(resp) {
        if (resp != null) {
          alert(resp);
          var myJSON = JSON.stringify(resp);
          alert(myJSON);
          sendData(myJSON);

          setInterval(ajaxCall, 1000 * 60);
        } else {
          alert("something went wrong");
        }
      }     
    });
  });
```

Comment: Every success call you make an interval..... Did you mean to use `setTimeout`?

Comment: Please remove `async: false`. It's *incredibly* bad practice. You can also remove the jQuery object wrapping the `ajaxCall()` function

Comment: after every minute i again want the data that is why i have used setInterval

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to move calling method to Ajax's complete method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function ajaxCall() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://blockchain.info/ticker",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            processData: true,
            success: function (resp) {
                if (resp !== null) {
                    alert(resp);
                    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(resp);
                    alert(myJSON);
                    sendData(myJSON);


                } else {
                    alert("something went wrong");
                }
            },
            complete: function () {
                setInterval(ajaxCall, 1000 * 60);
            }
        });
    })
});
```